# Load webform submission

Tags: 8, webforms

How can I load a webform submission programmatically ?

I've tried : `$webform_submission = WebformSubmission::load($sid);`

but it return null.

I do this in a custom module call by an handler after webform submission.

Comment: What is the content of the variable $sid?

Comment: It's a submission ID

Comment: I meant the actual content, this would be the first step to debug this.

Comment: I'm getting the submission ID from a custom handler, the data is send by GET to my controller (ID is 1051 currently)

Comment: Did you check if the sid 1051 exists in admin/structure/webform/submissions/manage?

Comment: Yes it does exist, I've double checked it

Comment: Then you need to debug this step-by-step, you've mentioned a controller and a handler, so check how the sid gets from the GET request to the controller and then to the handler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have to load sid like below

```
// Load submission using sid.
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid);
```

Answer (score 4):

To load webform submissions of a particular webform programmatically -

```
    $webform = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load('WEBFORM_ID');  //webform id is the webform name
    if ($webform->hasSubmissions()) {
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
        ->condition('webform_id', 'WEBFORM_ID');
      $result = $query->execute();
      $submission_data = [];
      foreach ($result as $item) {
        $submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($item);
        $submission_data = $submission->getData();
      }
    }
```